# SQL Server change tracking has cleaned up tracking information - Error

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework, change-tracking

Does anyone know how to fix this error on Microsoft Sync Framework: SQL Server change tracking has cleaned up tracking information for table ... ?

Answer (score 0):

if SQL CT has indeed clean up the Change Tracking info, there's not much you can do about it.  you will have to reinitialize your clients